# Where can I find custom element class methods in the Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

If I have a custom element implemented like this:

```
class PlaybackControls extends HTMLElement {
    // example method
    changeState() {
        [...]
    }
}
```

I can see Chrome knows about the method because it suggests it in the Console:

[image: Console]

**Is there a place in the dev tools that shows all the class methods that a custom element implements?**

I thought they might be here:

[image: Properties]

But it seems they are not. I may have missed them (there's a ton of stuff), so if they are supposed to be in there, where would they be under?

Thank you.

Comment: Click the triangle to the left of `playback-controls.stopped` in the panel.

Comment: I don't know. And this probably won't help you since you're looking at your own code, but for anyone else who wants to look at someone else's custom element, they could try using `customElements.get('element-name');` to get the constructor, then copy it into an IDE to see methods, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/get